# Angular 5 App Architecture design

Tags: angular, angular5, single-page-application, enterprise

**I've few questions related to Angular 5 App design -**

We're designing an enterprise app which is something like placeholder of Widgets and Widgets Store. It works like this - When user lands on the page, he will see few widgets which he can customize. If he wish, he can add more widgets from Store.

When he add Widgets, it will be updated dynamically to the page. You can think each widget as Component. Having said that, I've few questions -

1. Without adding the components to **entryComponents** array of the **NgModule** can we add components dynamically? (I know the other as ComponentResolverFactory). Is there anything else?

I'm asking this because, if we start adding more components (Widgets), which are dynamically loaded, we have to end up adding those in **entryComponents** and inturn will increase the initial module size this affecting the performance.

2. We're planning to create a Angular Shell, where we can load Angular apps can load dynamically based on configuration.

Some thing like Shell holds - Header & Footer and the content is another Angular app which can loaded.

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Question1. No, dynamically created components must be declared in `entryComponents`, or else you will get an error

Comment: you can use angular's compiler to load components dynamically, it's really heavy though. This [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) is enough to get you going.

Comment: Yes, we've already gone through that article. Tweak to lazy load the components, if we have less component to load. We're looking for enterprise scale app which has 100+ components to load.

Moreover we can't bloat each component with module configurations which may not be righteous approach for our scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> Without adding the components to entryComponents array of the NgModule
>   can we add components dynamically? (I know the other as
>   ComponentResolverFactory). Is there anything else?

You can lazy load modules which has components(widgets). But it's tightly coupled with routing system. So, you should **navigate** to lazy load modules

**route example:**

```
{
   path: 'lazy-load-path',
   loadChildren: 'path/to/lazy#Module'
}
```

As application is SPA, it can be configured. As your example,

> When user lands on the page, he will see few widgets which he can
>   customize. If he wish, he can add more widgets from Store

So, to add more widgets to store:

1. Create `<router-outlet>` in current page template

   **current-page.template:**

   ```
   ....
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   ...
   ```
2. Configure current page's route

   **current-module.routing.ts:**

   ```
   {
      path: 'current-page',
      component: 'CurrentComponent',
      children: [
        {
           path: 'lazyModule1', 
           loadChildren: 'path/to/lazy#Module1'
        },
        {
           path: 'lazyModule2',
           loadChildren: 'path/to/lazy#Module2'
        }
       ....
      ]
   }
   ```

   Each lazy module will consist some widgets. As current page have `router-outlet`, lazy module components will be placed to here as child.
3. > If he wish, he can add more widgets from Store

   To add widgets in `current-page-component` need to navigate to `lazyModule1`/`lazyModule2`. And it's trivial task. Navigate by template `routerLink` or by component class injecting `Router` and `router.navigate('lazyModule1')` ...

Comment: Thanks Yerkon for your thoughts! Lazy loading module was not an option for us since the widgets can be in 100's. We're looking something for component lazy loading which is not available out of the box in Angular.